# Styling for overflowing 2 text containers side by side

Tags: javascript, css, angular

Hi so I am styling something which displays both the user username and the title of the item on the same line, something along the lines of:

username / title (similar to github)

i want to style it such that if the full width of username / title is less than the container width, it should display the full text of both, but if they exceed the max width of the container and start to overflow i want them to keep to about a 50-50 or maybe 40-60 ratio with ellipsis, like this:

long_usern... / long_ti...

so far i've screwed around a bit with max-width and min-width and percentages, and i've ended up with this final state:

```
.username {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.title{
    min-width: 50%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9csohvpa/4/

however when the title is too long sometimes it obscures the username to the point where it is only a few dots and does not hold any meaning.

```
... / super_duper_ultra_long...
```

sometimes it manages to still show a bit of the username while overflowing the rest of the long title, although i do not really understand how it works and how priority is given to each element in this case about how much of the full width it is allowed to take up. i'd like the username to take up at least 30-40% of the width no matter how long the text in each element is.

its fine if the solution gives a hard limit on the username like doesn't allow it to go over 40% width in the case of long username with short title that doesn't fill up the to max width because it looks a little silly with a long username and short title.

i've tried min-width for the username class but in the case of a short username there is a lot of blank space before the slash and i don't want that.

```
i      / loveyou
```

i've also tried max-width 50-50 but with a short username and long title the title doesn't fill up the remainder of the space in the width of the flex container like i want it to

```
i / hateyousomu...         |
                           | <-- maximum available width for container
username / long_title_na...|
                           |
i / hateyousomuch555       | <-- ideal solution
```

in any case, the ideal solution should manage to keep the elements at about an 40-60 ratio of the max-width when the sum of widths of both element exceeds the maximum available width of the container, but show the full width of text in both elements otherwise

**Edit:** Thanks @robbieAreBest for answering, and uncovering that adding `width: fit-content` to the .username class doesn't work for some reason (in fact it has no effect on the width of the class at all). Through this I uncovered that the percentage width the username section takes up in the container is directly proportional to its length, and the 50/50 ratio holds up only when the length of the username is about the same as the length of the title or longer (e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/pys25tfa/). Does anyone know why this happens or how to fix it? Would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit 2 + [existing solution I'm willing to make do with](https://jsfiddle.net/eu2t0fq3/1/):** 
Solution has been found, but every solution has room for improvements. Current solution only considers the basic 4 cases I mentioned about and limits the username to about 40% of the total width even with a short title. If I missed out any possible combinations, if someone manages to find a case where my code breaks, or if someone manages to find a better solution which deals with long username/short title case better, please do let me know.

The ideal code (which may be a tad bit specific/unnecessary): Long username with long title that combined overflow the full width will limit the width of each element at 40/60 ratio respectively, but a long username and short title which does not overflow the full width limits the username to about 60% of the width instead, allowing more info to be displayed to the user. If anyone manages to find a solution which displays the full username in the case of long username and short title please do post below as well. Thanks all for your effort to help me :) I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add `width: fit-content` to your `.username` class

```
.username {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: fit-content;
}

.title{
    min-width: 50%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

This should let the username shrink and give more space to your `.title span` while also taking up half the available area if needed.

---

EDIT AFTER COMMENT

If the above doesn't give you the results you are after you might want to try using grid display instead:

html:

```
<div class="wrap">
<span class="username">usern</span>
<span class="title">&nbsp;/ super_duper_long_title</span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.username {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.title{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.wrap {
  display: grid;
  width: 150px;
  grid-template-columns: auto minmax(20%,100%);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eu2t0fq3/1/

Comment: Hi robbie, thanks for your answer. It certainly sounded correct in theory, and worked for longer usernames, but unfortunately usernames which are shorter than the title still faced unequal ratios for some reason. e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/Ly3dvbrj/1/

Does anyone know why this happens or whether there is a workaround?

Comment: I see how that would be undesirable. I've edited my answer with another solution that might get you what you want.

Comment: Hey thanks, I never considered grid before :)
Unfortunately, https://jsfiddle.net/wv479s1b/ :(
Problem now comes in when both are short

Comment: Thank you so much Robbie! After looking at your idea for using grid to do this, I read up on grid myself and managed to come up with a solution! However, it only considers the basic 4 cases I mentioned about and limits the username to about 40% of the total width even with a short title. Do get back to me if you managed to find a better solution though, or if you find any cases which break the code.

Solution: https://jsfiddle.net/eu2t0fq3/1/

Comment: On the other hand, it would be great if you could edit your answer to include the solution and then I can mark it as correct :) I believe your efforts fully deserves the mark for the correct answer together with whatever benefits it entails. I also would prefer for people to find the solution in the answers instead of the question itself so it wouldn't be confusing or anything.

Comment: I'm happy you got something that worked for you! I've edited the answer to include your measurements and a link to the final JSFiddle